# how to append output of a function in a Vector in R

Tags: r

I am calculating the mode of column based on the other column, but I am not able to append the return of a function to a vector:
    `getmode <- function(v) {
     uniqv <- unique(v)
     uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
    }`

Above function give me the mode of a column. When I call the function I get the
output in the following way:

```
x<-income_train$workclass[income_train$educational_num == '16']
x
```

Output:

```
[1] Private
Levels: ? Federal-gov Local-gov Never-worked Private Self-emp-inc Self-emp-not-inc State-gov Without-pay
```

Now I want to create a function that for each value of educational_num column i.e 1 to 16 I get the mode for work class. So I wrote code:

```
`z <-c()
 for (i in 1:16){
  x<-NULL
  x<-income_train$workclass[income_train$educational_num == i]
  result <- getmode(income_train$workclass)
  print(result)
  z <- c(z,result)

 }
 print(z)`
```

Above code is giving me output like below:

```
[1] Private
Levels: ? Federal-gov Local-gov Never-worked Private Self-emp-inc Self-emp-  not-inc State-gov Without-pay
[1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

I don't know from where 5 is coming. I want it to result to contain 16 "Private". Which proves that for each and every value of educational_num column mode of workplace column is "Private". Please help.

Comment: this line `result <- getmode(income_train$workclass)` I think you should make it `result <- getmode(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, try to provide a dataset with `dput` so that others can have an easier time understanding your data.

Try using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(income_train)
income_train[, getmode(workclass), educational_num]
```

This effectively calls getmode on each group on educational_num.

Hope this works for you.